# setTimeout fires twice or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    let sudokuBodyWidth = $sudokuBody.outerWidth(true);
    let sudokuBodyHeight = $sudokuBody.outerHeight(true);

    console.log(sudokuBodyWidth + ',' + sudokuBodyHeight);

    $sudoku.hide();
    $welcomeOverlay.css({
        width: sudokuBodyWidth,
        height: sudokuBodyHeight
    }).show();
}, 800);

window.clearTimeout();
```

I've put this code in a setTimeout because it takes a lot of time the DOM to load, so the JS code is to early with executing and returns 0 for the values (it's a huge codebase and I'm not 'allowed' to change the site structure to make the JS load later).

The problem is that this code runs twice. First, it returns the correct result, but then it returns 0 for both variables immediately after the correct values. As you can see, I've added a clearTimeout to prevent the execution to happen twice. But it keeps executing twice.

I've also tried:

```
let welcomeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // the code
});

clearTimeout(welcomeTimeout);
```

When doing this, the code doesn't execute at all.

Comment: That code will not run twice... My guess is, it is included twice and `window.clearTimeout();` is not going to do a thing

Comment: Well, you can put your code inside window.onload = function() { };

Comment: It will only run twice if you execute the setTimeout function twice so it means that you are loading/calling this script twice

Comment: @Alex Nothing happens when I do that either.

Comment: @kimy82 This timeout is inside a constructor method and an object of it's class is created only once. There's no other setTimeout anywhere in my code either (but it did work normally in another project for the same site). And, when I put the timeout in a variable, it's not executing twice, but not at all.

Comment: @erol_smsr It is impossible for what you have to run twice. The only explaination is it is included twice. Ans when you call `clearTimeout(welcomeTimeout);` you are killing the timeout before it runs...

Comment: Try to run console.trace(); inside setTimeout

Comment: @Alex It only gives two warnings about a script that has nothing to do with this one and it's about a timed out XMLHttpRequest. I don't think this code has anything traceable :/

Comment: Try to set a break point in that line "window.setTimeout(function() {" to make sure it is going through that code twice

Comment: Also, that is not how clearTimeout works...

Comment: const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
clearTimeout(timeoutId);

Comment: It doesn't go through the timeout at all. The timeout is directly inside a constructor method and when I don't put the timeout inside a variable it runs twice, when I do put it inside a variable it doesn't run at all.

Comment: BECAUSE IT IS INCLUDED TWICE!!! That is the only way it is going to run twice. When you cancel it, you kill the timeout.... It is not going to run....

Comment: So was it included twice @erol_smsr??

Comment: I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.clearTimeout()` will do nothing because you are not passing the timerId witch get returned by `window.setTimeout()` and this should not run twice there is something else witch is causing this function to run twice

and in second one `clearTimeout(welcomeTimeout);` clears the timer that's why your code doesn't run

if you want to run your code after the document get loaded fully then you can use `window.onload = function(){...}`

or if you are using jQuery then you can also try `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: The example in the comments by @alex in combination with window.onload did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It should execute only once check Ur code base if u r loading script two times mean while put clearTimeout code at the end in the ananymous  function given to setTimeout function

Answer (score 1):

Putting the code at the end of HTML executes it when the DOM is loaded.
Use this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script async src="..."></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        ...
        <script>(function() { init(); })();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Function `init()` will fire when the DOM is ready.

Also you're using `setTimeout()` wrong, take a look at [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
var what_to_do = function(){ do_stuff(); };
var when_to_do = 3000; // 3000ms is 3 seconds

var timer = setTimeout(what_to_do, when_to_do);
```

Comment: Thanks! But I also mentioned in the question that it's a huge codebase and there are tons of external JS scripts, so I can't just change the placements of JS files (which get bundled inside multiple files) inside the templates (it will break other things).

Comment: @erol_smsr Do not, just place the self-executing function at the bottom to catch DOM load, and then do everything in `init()`